# Any modern, newer, better alernatives to Ariel Flesler's scrollTo/serialScroll?

Tags: jquery-plugins, scroll, slideshow, scrollto, serialscroll

I'm using both scrollTo and the "child"-plugin serialScroll quite frequently, and like them because they

1. Actually SCROLL things, rather than animating css-properties (margin/position etc)
2. Are flexible and can be used in many different situations, unlike lots of other scroller/sliders that adds a bunch of bells and whistles that you don't really need.

Thing is, the plugins haven't been updated since 2009, and although they still work just fine, regardless of jquery version, there are things that could need improving (like the ability to change settings after initilaisation), and overall it doesn't fell optimal to use a 3 year old plugin, solid and stable as it is.

Does anyone have a suggestion of other plugins that might do the same thing, perhaps better?

http://flesler.blogspot.se/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but for the record, as Shauna said, the plugins aren't outdated, OP might have been looking at Google code hosting which is indeed out of date.

The plugin is now hosted on [Github](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo). There's no much of a need to update it too often given it's very stable already, but I do land some commits every now and then when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a suggestion for anything better (even Google is coming up with Flesler's plugin or hand-written from base JavaScript or jQuery), but Flesler is still updating the plugin. You can find the [latest version in GitHub](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo).